Why can't I buy the ETF "AXA IM NSDQ USD ACC" in my PEA?
I have opened my PEA (Plan d'épargne en actions) on Boursobank and tries to buy this ETF AXA IM Nasdaq UCITS ETF (https://www.justetf.com/uk/etf-profile.html?isin=IE000QDFFK00#overview ) but I have received the following error message:
Erreur
Cette valeur n'est pas négociable. Pour plus d'informations, veuillez consulter notre polituqe d'exécution.
Can anyone tell me if this ETF is eligible for PEA, living in France, please?

Do you need that specific ETF or will any Nasdaq 100 ETF do?

Have you asked customer support? The error message seems to be very generic

I click on the link and the first thing I see on JustETF is a red banner that reads This product does only have marketing distribution rights for Austria, Switzerland, Germany, Denmark, Spain, France, Ireland, Italy, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, Sweden
